# Question about rvs boundary in scipy.stats.randint

Tags: python-3.x, scipy

I'm using the scipy.stats.randint to get random numbers.

Here is my source code and result.

**Input:**

from scipy.stats import randint
randint.rvs(0.00001, 10, size=100)

**Output:**

array([6, 4, 6, 7, 9, 7, 3, 0, 2, 5, 1, 1, 0, 3, 6, 7, 3, 6, 4, 8, 6, 5,
       0, 0, 5, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 0, 6, 5, 2, 0, 0, 9, 1, 5, 2, 3, 6, 1, 4,
       3, 1, 4, 4, 9, 5, 6, 3, 4, 3, 7, 7, 2, 4, 0, 2, 0, 6, 8, 1, 5, 6,
       4, 6, 5, 0, 8, 8, 5, 9, 3, 2, 8, 7, 1, 4, 6, 0, 7, 3, 9, 1, 2, 7,
       7, 6, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 7, 7, 4, 1, 1])

My question is, I've set the low to 0.000001, but How the '0's came out from output.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scipy's randint invokes `mtrand.randint`, that is a part of Numpy package.
As you can see from its [source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/d1d862dd8eb7e560342895dfb5e69bf7c7702110/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.pyx#L984), lower bound is truncated using (int)(low).
So, to get random numbers from closed interval [1, 10], do the following:

```
randint.rvs(1, 11, size=100)
```

Note, you need to increase high bound by 1, as it seen from the form of [probability distribution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.randint.html#scipy.stats.randint) (pmf) for randint.